# How do I do a peer review?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Where can I find lists of posts that need to be peer reviewed?
These would be the accept or reject proofreads that count towards the `proofreader` badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find these at [stackoverflow.com/review.](https://stackoverflow.com/review)

However, you won't be able to do any yet. To do *any* reviews, you need 500 reputation. To do *suggested edit* reviews, the ones you need for the "Proofreader" badge, you need 2,000 reputation. 2,000 reputation is *also* when you get the privilege to edit posts without having your edits approved, which is needed for the review queue in case you wish to improve a suggestion or reject it and replace it with your own edit.

You can still manage to review suggested edits before 2,000 reputation, but only if other users with less than 2,000 reputation suggest edits on your posts. It's unlikely that you'll get 100 of those before you get 2,000 rep, but it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) in order to access that queue. Your edits aren't applied automatically until you have 2,000 rep.